# Storing InkCanvas in custom class (?)

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

I'm writing a simple application for my students and I'm stuck in a middle of my work. So, here's what is it about - it's a simple app for managing also very simple notebooks. Each notebook contains a textbox and InkCanvas, in which users can draw simple shapes. Clicking on a desired notebook binds it to țe fields in app, so they're updated in fly. Saving is done via xml serialization.

Notebook is a custom class, and creating a new one, creates a new instance of this class. Here's the code:

```
namespace Notes.Classes
{
[Serializable]
public class Notebook : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [XmlAttribute("Notebook")]
    private string Name;

    [XmlElement("Notebook content")]
    private string Content;

    private DateTime Date;


    #region OnPropertyChanged
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public Notebook(string Name, string Content)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Date = DateTime.Now;
        if (Content == "")
            this.Content = "Write something";
        else
            this.Content = Content;
    }

    //This is never used private parameterless constructor created only because Serialization required one
    //It is private, so it can't create new notebooks when not needed
    private Notebook()
    {
        this.Name = "bez nazwy";
        this.Content = "bez zawartości";
    }

    #endregion

    [XmlElement("Notebook date")]
    public string GetDate
    {
        get { return Date.ToString(); }
        set { Date = DateTime.Parse(value); OnPropertyChanged("Date"); }
    }

    public string GetName
    {
        get { return Name; }
        set { Name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }
    public string GetContent
    {
        get { return Content; }
        set { Content = value; OnPropertyChanged("Content"); }
    }

    public string GetPath
    {
        get { return InkPath;}
        set { InkPath = value; OnPropertyChanged("InkPath"); }
    }
   }
 }
```

Now what I need done is somehow vinding InkCanvas Strokes to a property of the class, saving it each time I close the app and loading everytime I choose a different notebook. It would be soo cool if I could simpky serialize it. Nothing fancy in the onkcanvas, no image uploading or bitmaps. Any quick and efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save the `StrokeCollection` from your `InkCanvas`. The [`StrokeCollection` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.ink.strokecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an overloaded [`Save` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590544%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you can use to save the `Stroke` data to a `Stream`. From the linked `Save` method page:

```
FileStream fs = null;

try
{
    fs = new FileStream(inkFileName, FileMode.Create);
    inkCanvas1.Strokes.Save(fs);
}
finally
{
    if (fs != null)
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: So my class should store only a filename and then loading it each time I open a notebook? Hm, I'll give it a try